# BEM: Modifier of a block effects all elements - best practice?

Tags: css, bem

What is the best practice if a modifier effects all elements of a block?

In my current project I have a header. This header changes to position: fixed if the user scrolls.

In the header there's the main navigation, the logo, a language switcher and a phone link:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">...</div>
  <nav class="nav nav_main">...</nav>
  <nav class="nav nav_lang-switch">...</nav>
  <div class="header__phone-link"></div>
</header>
```

On scrolling, the header get's the modifier *header_fixed*:

```
<header class="header header_fixed">
  <div class="header__logo">...</div>
  <nav class="nav nav_main">...</nav>
  <nav class="nav nav_lang-switch">...</nav>
  <div class="header__phone-link"></div>
</header>
```

The header looks completely different if it's fixed: the color changes, the main navigation turns to a hamburger icon navigation, the icons of the lang switch become smaller and so on.

Now I could go the nested way in CSS:

```
.header_fixed .nav_main {...}
.header_fixed .lang-switch__icon {...}
.header_fixed .header__phone-link {...}
...
```

Or every block or element that changed can get it's own modifier class.

What are your thoughts about that?

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338574/can-we-make-an-element-of-block-modifier-in-bem/47339603#47339603 ?

Answer (score 2):

Nesting is just fine here, see https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#nested-selectors